# Create 2D array of complex numbers in numpy

Tags: numpy

I wish to create a 2D array of NxN complex numbers of arbitrary size. So (for sake of simplicity) a N=3 array might be of the form

```
[
  [0.0 + 0.0j, 0.0 + 1.0j, 0.0 + 2.0j]
  [1.0 + 0.0j, 1.0 + 1.0j, 1.0 + 2.0j]
  [2.0 + 0.0j, 2.0 + 1.0j, 2.0 + 2.0j]
]
```

(in reality N would be > 3). I can create a 1D array using e.g. `np.linspace()`. Is there a similar facility to generate a 2D one? I imagine that N would be of the order of 50 or 100 with the real and imaginary parts ranging from -2*np.pi to 2*np.pi or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use broadcasting here:

```
N=5
np.arange(N)[:,None] + np.complex('j')* np.arange(N)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.+0.j, 0.+1.j, 0.+2.j, 0.+3.j, 0.+4.j],
       [1.+0.j, 1.+1.j, 1.+2.j, 1.+3.j, 1.+4.j],
       [2.+0.j, 2.+1.j, 2.+2.j, 2.+3.j, 2.+4.j],
       [3.+0.j, 3.+1.j, 3.+2.j, 3.+3.j, 3.+4.j],
       [4.+0.j, 4.+1.j, 4.+2.j, 4.+3.j, 4.+4.j]])
```

Or in your case:

```
N=50
x = np.linspace(-2,2,N) * np.pi

out = x[:,None] + np.complex('j') * x
```